# React fetch - initial state not loading - what can I do?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have started to learn react two days ago, so I am a complete newbie. I am attempting to create a simple website app that loads beer data (image, name, tagline) from a public API on cards. Upon clicking on the card, it should display description, name, tagline.
My problem is that upon initial load, no data loads - each card only loads after I click on it.[after clicking one card twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG7RO.png)
It was working fine before I introduced the clicking function and backFacingCard.

I tried several things, including making separate components for each card side but like I said, I am still very new to react and coding in general, so I am not sure if what I do is correct. I would be very grateful for any tips and tricks.

Here is my code for the card component:

```
const BeerTile = (props) => {
  const frontFacingCard = {
    src: (
      <Card
        hoverable
        size="small"
        style={{
          width: 350,
          height: 220,
        }}
        cover={
          <img
            className="beer_tile_card_img"
            alt="beer-bottle"
            src={props.beer?.image_url}
          />
        }
      >
        <Meta
          className="meta"
          title={props.beer?.name}
          description={props.beer?.tagline}
        />
      </Card>
    ),
  };

  const backFacingCard = {
    src: (
      <Card
        hoverable
        size="small"
        style={{
          width: 350,
          height: 220,
        }}
        cover={
          <div className="beer-description">{props.beer?.description}</div>
        }
      >
        <Meta
          className="meta"
          title={props.beer?.name}
          description={props.beer?.tagline}
        />
      </Card>
    ),
  };

  const [card, setCard] = useState(frontFacingCard.src);
  const [showsFront, setShowsFront] = useState(true);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    if (showsFront) {
      setCard(backFacingCard.src);
      setShowsFront(false);
      props.frontSide(showsFront);
    } else {
      setCard(frontFacingCard.src);
      setShowsFront(true);
      props.frontSide(showsFront);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="beer_tile_card"
      onClick={clickHandler}
      front={showsFront ? 1 : 0}
    >
      {card}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for rendering the `BeerTile`

Answer (score 0):

in your second component you can use useEffect

```
const [card, setCard] = useState(frontFacingCard.src);
  const [showsFront, setShowsFront] = useState(true);

useEffect(()=>{
console.log("frontFacingCard.src",frontFacingCard.src)//check if source is available
setCard(frontFacingCard.src)
},[frontFacingCard.src])

  const clickHandler = () => {
    if (showsFront) {
      setCard(backFacingCard.src);
      setShowsFront(false);
      props.frontSide(showsFront);
    } else {
      setCard(frontFacingCard.src);
      setShowsFront(true);
      props.frontSide(showsFront);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="beer_tile_card"
      onClick={clickHandler}
      front={showsFront ? 1 : 0}
    >
      {card}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this alternate solution

```
    const BeerTile = (props) => {
  const FrontFacingCard = () => {
    return (
      <Card
        hoverable
        size="small"
        style={{
          width: 350,
          height: 220,
        }}
        cover={
          <img
            className="beer_tile_card_img"
            alt="beer-bottle"
            src={props.beer?.image_url}
          />
        }
      >
        <Meta
          className="meta"
          title={props.beer?.name}
          description={props.beer?.tagline}
        />
      </Card>
    )
  };

  const BackFacingCard =()=> {
    return (
      <Card
        hoverable
        size="small"
        style={{
          width: 350,
          height: 220,
        }}
        cover={
          <div className="beer-description">{props.beer?.description}</div>
        }
      >
        <Meta
          className="meta"
          title={props.beer?.name}
          description={props.beer?.tagline}
        />
      </Card>
    )
  };

  const [showsFront, setShowsFront] = useState(true);

  const clickHandler = () => {
      setShowsFront(!showFront);
      props.frontSide(showsFront);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="beer_tile_card"
      onClick={clickHandler}
      front={showsFront ? 1 : 0}
    >
      {
    showsFront
       ? <FrontFacingCard />
       : <BackFacingCard />
    }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this cleaner solution, that separate back,front and Tile.

```
const BeerTile = (props) => {
  const [front, setFront] = useState(true);

  const clickHandler = () => {
     setFront(!front)
    
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="beer_tile_card"
      onClick={clickHandler}
      front={showsFront ? 1 : 0}
    >
      {front?<FrontFacingCard {...props}/>:<BackFacingCard {...props}/> }
    </div>
  );
};

  const FrontFacingCard=(props)=>
     (
      <Card
        hoverable
        size="small"
        style={{
          width: 350,
          height: 220,
        }}
        cover={
          <img
            className="beer_tile_card_img"
            alt="beer-bottle"
            src={props.beer?.image_url}
          />
        }
      >
        <Meta
          className="meta"
          title={props.beer?.name}
          description={props.beer?.tagline}
        />
      </Card>
    ),
  };

  const BackFacingCard =( props)=>(
      <Card
        hoverable
        size="small"
        style={{
          width: 350,
          height: 220,
        }}
        cover={
          <div className="beer-description">{props.beer?.description}</div>
        }
      >
        <Meta
          className="meta"
          title={props.beer?.name}
          description={props.beer?.tagline}
        />
      </Card>
    );
```